# i lose my linked tables when closing access

Tags: ms-access-2003

i create a linked table and it works fine. but when i close access and open it again the table is gone. why is that happening ?

i am using access 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have resolved this, but I have had the same problem years ago.  I speculate it is due to a corrupt database.

My *workaround* was to copy all the objects from one database to a new database.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the MDB file does not have a read-only attribute or other restriction on updating it.